# EntityManager Merge Inserts new entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Greetings SO Community

I've been having a problem with Hibernate JPA: whenever I call `entityManger.merge(entity)`, Hibernate tries to insert it. I migrated from OpenJPA where it was working correctly, but I can't get this working no matter what I do.

I've been searching in SO and Google for a solution to the problem, or at least something that points me in the right direction, with no luck. The post that is closest to my issue, has not been answered: [entitymanager merge insert instead of update JPA Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297319/entitymanager-merge-insert-instead-of-update-jpa-hibernate)

I am trying to insert an entity `Organization` which has an unidirectional `@OneToOne` relationship with the `User` entity. I have added `Casecade.Persist` so the `User` entity is only affected when creating/persisting the `Organization`. The persist operation works as expected. However, as menetioned before, `merge` doesn't work as expected, instead, it tries to persist/insert.

**Can someone please help me solve this problem?**

I would like to use only JPA Hibernate and stay away from Hibernate specific implementations in case I ever need to migrate to another JPA provider.

Environment:

This is a **Maven** project and I am using **Wildfly 10**

Below is my code:

I use a `MappedSuperClass` for the usual SQL fields:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable{
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    //[UPDATE] I omitted the version field thinking it wasn't relevant, but now I believe this is the root of my problem. If I remove this field merge works as expected.
    @Version
    Long version
    // getters and setters
}
```

The entity I am trying to insert:

```
@Entity
public class Organization extends BaseEntity{

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true, insertable = true)
    private User user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The `User` entity:

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 45)
    private String firstName;
    @Size(max = 45)
    private String lastName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

I try to merge the entity in a `JAX-RS` rest method:

```
@Path("{id}")
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Organization edit(Organization entity,
                         @PathParam("id") Long id) {
    //Omitting how I got the userId as it is not relevant to the situation at hand
    entity.setUser(entityManager.find(User.class, userId));
    super.edit(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

Note:

- The entity object above, which I pass as a JSON object in the request and is marshalled by Jackson, contains all the necessary fields, **[especially the primary key (id)]**.
- Both entities, and the MappedSuperClass, are in the persistence.xml

I enabled `hibernate.show_sql` in `persistence.xml` in order to see what was going on:

`<property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />`

Below is the stacktrace of the exception I get:

```
17:58:08,804 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Hibernate: insert into Organization (createdBy, lastUpdatedBy, version, description, name, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  
17:58:09,302 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
17:58:09,303 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_5lqexr38qf28ptx0lhuhqor9w'
17:58:09,401 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-4) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component OrganizationFacadeREST for method public com.scholarjet.model.Organization com.scholarjet.service.OrganizationFacadeREST.edit(com.scholarjet.model.Organization,java.lang.Long): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.scholarjet.service.OrganizationFacadeREST$$$view4.edit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.scholarjet.service.OrganizationFacadeREST$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.edit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.merge(AbstractEntityManager.java:565)
    at com.scholarjet.service.AbstractFacade.edit(AbstractFacade.java:32)
    at com.scholarjet.service.OrganizationFacadeREST.edit(OrganizationFacadeREST.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2792)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3363)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_5lqexr38qf28ptx0lhuhqor9w'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 138 more
```

[UPDATE]

JSON Object submitted in PUT request:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "2 My Org 1",
  "description": "2 Org 1 Description 1"
}
```

In terms of `toString` output, I haven't override (overriden?) the `toString` method of this object. So right now it is returning the default `toString` method in `Object`:

`com.francisco.model.Organization@1`

In case it helps, I have put a breakpoint in the line where I call `super.edit(entity)` and ran the debugger. This is the content of `entity`:

[image: Contents of entity when stopped in breakpoint]

I should also note that `super.edit(entity)` just calls: 
`entityManager.merge(entity)`

Comment: I gotta ask the obvious question: is the pk field populated before the merge?

Comment: Yes, I mention it in the post but given that you missed it, it might not be clear. I will update the post to point that out. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Could you please show the JSON being submitted as well as perhaps a toString() output of the values inside your entity prior to calling merge?

Comment: I have updated the post with the JSON being submitted, the output of toString() and the values inside the entity prior to calling merge.

Comment: JSON has only Organization fields.  Debug screenshot shows a User associated with Organization - how is that User object getting loaded?

Comment: The user associated with the Organization is added before the `edit(entity)` method is called. I left it out because I didn't think it was necessary. I'll add it.

Comment: Debug and work out whether the OBJECT passed to merge is effectively in managed state. If it is then the JSON stuff is irrelevant to the whole problem and would simplify the "question"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I omitted the version field thinking it wasn't relevant, but now I believe this is the root of my problem. If I remove this field merge works as expected.

This is because of how `@Version` and optimisitic-locking work.

I always prefer not exposing the `@Version` property to the outside world because it allows some external event to force an update in cases where I need an `OptimisiticLockException` to tbe thrown when the same row is modified by multiple sessions simultaneously.

What you want to do is leverage the transfer object pattern and overlay the incoming data atop of the actual database object:

```
@Path("{id}")
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Organization edit(OrganizationDTO dto,
                     @PathParam("id") Long id) {
  // lookup entity from database
  Organization org = entityManager.find( Organization.class, entity.getId() );
  // map changable values to the entity
  org.setName( dto.getName() );
  org.setDescription( dto.getDescription() );
  org.setUser( entityManager.find( User.class, userId ) );
  dto.setUser( org.getUser() );
  // merge changes
  entityManager.merge( org );
  // return dto
  return dto;
}
```

I believe you can leverage `ObjectMapper` to where you can do the mapping overlays without having to necessarily hard code it; I'll leave that as an exercise.

But the point here is that the root of your problem is that you're trying to treat your incoming JSON data a complete `Organization` object and attempt to update it in your database when in reality it's partial data.

If the version value had been provided in your initial JSON, hibernate would have worked with merge as you expected, assuming the version value provided matched that of the value in your database.  A non-null value that didn't match would have raised an `OptimisticLockException`.

Comment: @Francisco C. can you please take a look at this question. Similar to what you posted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797162/hibernate-update-table-with-foreign-key